# Standalone Drools : Dynamic facts handling

Tags: java, drools, drools-kie-server

We are trying to migrate an application which uses Drools v4 to Drools v7. For the new Drools version, the engine will be decoupled from the application i.e. there will be a kie-server which will interact via REST.

In the existing application, we have insertion of dynamic facts. As per the Drools v4 documentation, if there is any change in dynamic facts then rule engine re-triggers the rules associated with those facts automatically.

My query is how will this work when the engine is running on a separate kie-server? What is the best strategy to handle dynamic facts ?

If you can point me to some documentation, that is also fine.

Comment: I've never even _seen_ a drools 4 application, and I've been working in drools for nearly 10 years now. Is there no way to update that?

Comment: That is the overall intention to update the application to newer version of Drools. My query is specifically on how to handle "dynamic facts" in the newer paradigm where the engine runs on a separate server.

Comment: By dynamic facts, you are referring to those inserted using a `insert` command in the rhs of the rule? eg `insert(new Foo())` ? My oldest experience is with 5.0 and I can't seem to find the official 4.x docs online anymore.

Comment: I am referring to insert methods called on the session itself before firing of the rules. There is insert method which takes in two arguments - a fact and a boolean. The boolean represents whether the fact is dynamic or not.

Comment: Even I could not find official documentation, after some googling I found this -> https://docs.huihoo.com/drools/4.0.7/. What I am talking about is in section 2.5.4.7.